# CALayers didn't get resized on its UIView's bounds change. Why?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I have a `UIView` which has about 8 different `CALayer` sublayers added to its layer.
If **I modify the view's bounds** (animated), then the view itself shrinks (I checked it with a `backgroundColor`), but **the sublayers' size remains unchanged**.

How to solve this?

Comment: @DawnSong yes it is helpful... on macos only

Answer (score 162, accepted):

I used the same approach that Solin used, but there's a typo in that code.  The method should be:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];
  // resize your layers based on the view's new bounds
  mylayer.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

For my purposes, I always wanted the sublayer to be the full size of the parent view. Put that method in your view class.

Comment: @fishinear are you sure? it sounds like you are describing frame. bounds should, theoretically, always have 0,0 as its origin.

Comment: @griotspeak - that's actually not the case. See the description of the bounds property here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW1  -- "By default, the origin of the bounds rectangle is set to (0, 0) but you can change this value to display different portions of the view."

Comment: Many thanks, I have since learned of a few cases (scroll view, for one) where that is not true but I forgot about this comment.

Comment: Don't forget to call [super layoutSubviews], as this can cause unexpected behavior in various UIKit classes.

Comment: This didn't work very well for me with a self-sizing `UITextView` (scrollEnabled = NO) and auto layout. I had a text view pinned to its superview, which in turn had a `CALayer` at the bottom of itself (a border), and I wanted it to update border position when the text view's height changed. For some reason `layoutSubiews` was called way too late (and the layer position was animated).

Comment: Found a solution: To disable layer frame animation use `[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES]` and perform changes inside a transaction.

Answer (score 27):

Since CALayer on the iPhone does not support layout managers, I think you have to make your view's main layer a custom CALayer subclass in which you override `layoutSublayers` to set the frames of all sublayers. You must also override your view's `+layerClass` method to return the class of your new CALayer subclass.

Comment: Override +layerClass like in the case of OpenGL layer override? Think so.

Set the frames of the sublayers? Set to what? I have to calculate all the sublayers' frames/positions individually depending on the superlayers frame size?

Isn't there any "constraint-like", or "link-to-superlayer"-like solution? Oh, god, another day out of time-frame. CGLayers got resized, but was too laggy, CALayers are fast enough, but did not get resized. So many surprise. Thanks for the reply, anyway.

Comment: CALayer on the Mac has layout managers for this but they are not available on the iPhone. So yes, you have to calculate the frame sizes yourself. Another option could be to use subviews instead of sublayers. Then you could set the subviews' autoresizing masks accordingly.

Comment: Ya, UIViews are too performance expensive classes, thatswhy I use CALayers.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested. It works, and it is not. I resize the view animated, but the sublayers resizes in a different animation. Bloody hell, what to do now? What is the method to override in the CALayer subclass what invokes on EVERY (!) frame of the view's animation? Is there any?

Comment: Just bumped into this as well. Seems like the best option is to subclass CALayer as Ole said, but it seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

Comment: Regarding this very old QA, @OleBegemann 's solution of using layoutSublayers ... now `layoutSublayers#oflayer` ... But i had never heard of it before; have no idea how it works; and in extensive testing can't seem to get it to work !!!  Heh.

Answer (score 17):

I used this in the UIView.

```
-(void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    if (layer == self.layer)
    {
        _anySubLayer.frame = layer.bounds;
    }

super.layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer)
}
```

Works for me.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me in iOS 8.  Presumably would work in earlier versions.  I had a gradient background layer and needed to resize the layer when the device is rotated.

Comment: Worked for me, but it did need a call through to super

Comment: This is the best answer! Yeah I have tried layoutSubviews but it only breaks layout of my UITextField like leftView and rightView disappearing and more Text in UITextField disappearing. Maybe I have used extension instead of inheritance of UIView, but it was very buggy. THIS WORKS GREAT! THX

Comment: For a layer with custom drawing (`CALayerDelegate`'s `draw(_:in:)`), I had to also call `_anySubLayer.setNeedsDisplay()`. Then this worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. In a custom view's layer I added two more sublayers. In order to resize the sublayers (every time the custom view's boundaries change), I implemented the method `layoutSubviews` of my custom view; inside this method I just update each sublayer's frame to match the current boundaries of my subview's layer.

Something like this:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
   //keep the same origin, just update the width and height
   if(sublayer1!=nil){
      sublayer1.frame = self.layer.bounds;
   }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need the if(sublayer1!=nil), since ObjC defines messages to nil (in this case, -setFrame:) as a no-op returning 0.

Comment: Don't forget to call `[super layoutSubviews]`. Omitting this call can cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 9):

## 2017:

The literal answer to this question:

"CALayers didn't get resized on its UIView's bounds change. Why?"

is that for better or worse:

`needsDisplayOnBoundsChange`

defaults to false (!!) in `CALayer`.

solution,

```
class CircularGradientViewLayer: CALayer {
    
    override init() {
        
        super.init()
        needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override open func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        go crazy drawing in .bounds
    }
}
```

Indeed, I direct you to this QA

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47760444/294884

which explains, what the hell the critical `contentsScale` does. You usually need to set that, when you set `needsDisplayOnBoundsChange`.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3 Version**

In Custom cell, Add Following lines

Declare first

```
let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
```

Then add following lines

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    gradientLayer.frame = self.YourCustomView.bounds
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `super.layoutSubviews()`. Omitting this call can cause unexpected behavior in some views.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ole] wrote CALayer does not support autoresizing on iOS. So you should adjust layout manually. My option was to adjust layer's frame within (iOS 7 and earlier)

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

or (as of iOS 8)

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinato
```

Answer (score -1):

In your custom view, you need declare variable for your custom layer, don't declare variable in scope init. And just init it once time, don't try set null value and reinit

```swift
class CustomView:UIView {
    var customLayer:CALayer = CALayer()
    
    override func  layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        //        guard let _fillColor = self._fillColor else {return}
        initializeLayout()
    }
    private func initializeLayout() { 
        customLayer.removeFromSuperView()
        customLayer.frame = layer.bounds                    
        layer.insertSubview(at:0)
    }
}
```

Comment: do you really delete and add layer each time instead of changing its frame?)