# CAGradientLayer Mask add Opacity in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I'm trying to add opacity to my view. When I add a CAGradientlayer, I roughly get, what I planned, but have a few issues.

1. I can't change the color. No matter what values I use, I'll always get a white layer
2. Even though I wanted it to be distributed over the whole view, it seems like it has an offset to the left.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
let maskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
maskLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    
maskLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
maskLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    
maskLayer.colors = [UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.0).CGColor, UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor, UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.0).CGColor]
maskLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
maskLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height)
    
self.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the white, this is because a layer mask does not contribute to color, only transparency. Essentially, only the alpha component has an effect, and the R,G,B components of the layer mask are ignored.

About the offset, could it be because your view is getting resized, and your layer isn't kept up to date? If so you could see the answer to this other question: [CALayers didn't get resized on its UIView's bounds change. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504151/calayers-didnt-get-resized-on-its-uiviews-bounds-change-why)

Comment: Thanks for the clearification. When I apply layoutSubviews as suggested in your link, it clears an offset to the left and adds one instead to the bottom.

Comment: override func layoutSubviews() {
        lineLayer.frame = self.bounds
        super.layoutSubviews()
    } where lineLayer is a calayer that is added as a subview

Comment: Since I've been to slow to edit my comment: though this might not be the error of the cagradientlayer. The error is better described at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828134/uibezierpath-moved-half-aside

Comment: okay the offset to y was cause I've had a wrong underständing of uibezierpath.