# UIBezierPath moved half aside

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw along an UIBezierPath to a view. The weird thing is, it starts with an offset of 50% of the view.

[image]

The grey part is the view and the lines are what I'm drawing.

Here is my code:

```
lineLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height);

lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
lineLayer.lineDashPattern = [3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
lineLayer.lineWidth = lineLayer.bounds.height

var linePath = UIBezierPath()
linePath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(lineLayer.bounds)))
linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(lineLayer.bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(lineLayer.bounds)))
lineLayer.path = linePath.CGPath;
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: I've added a call to layoutSubview and it moved the offset from x to y:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay my error was, that I thought the UIBezierPath describes the edge of the drawing. Instead it describes the center. So I've changed my code to:

```
linePath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetMidY(lineLayer.bounds)))
linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(lineLayer.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(lineLayer.bounds)))
```

and it works