# Center CAShapeLayer within custom UIView Subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation, frame

I created a custom `UIView` subclass. In it, I created a `CAShapeLayer` as a mask for a `CAGradientLayer`. I am using Storyboards and with `@IBDesignable` everything looks ok in the Storyboard. This is how it looks which is perfect:

[image]

When I run the app in the Simulator, it does not appear ok:

[image]

This is the code which sets this up:

```
@IBDesignable
class ProgressView: UIView {

let progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setup()
}

func setup() {

    // Setup progress layer.
    progressLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    progressLayer.fillColor = nil
    progressLayer.strokeEnd = 1
    progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    progressLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

    let radius = CGFloat(self.frame.height / 2.5)
    let startAngle = CGFloat(-M_PI / 2)
    let endAngle = CGFloat(3 * M_PI / 2)
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)

    progressLayer.path = path.CGPath

    layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)


    // Setup gradient layer mask.
    gradientLayer.colors = [Constants.ColorPalette.teal.CGColor, Constants.ColorPalette.orange.CGColor, Constants.ColorPalette.pink.CGColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    gradientLayer.frame = self.frame
    gradientLayer.mask = progressLayer

    layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}

.....
```

I've tried changing the `frames` and using `awakeFromNib` and `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` to setup the view but it does not seem to work. I want to do everything within the `UIView` subclass and not a `UIViewController`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use layer frame instead of self:

```
  let radius = CGFloat(layer.frame.height / 2.5)
  ....
  gradientLayer.frame = layer.frame
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I just tried your suggestion but it still does not appear in the correct place. It's weird because `@IBDesignable` shows it correctly in Storyboard but in the Simulator it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe this solution will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504151/calayers-didnt-get-resized-on-its-uiviews-bounds-change-why

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but still no good : (    If you have anything else, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: did you try it with layer.frame?

Comment: Yes, I did `progressLayer.frame = layer.bounds` and `progressLayer.frame = self.bounds` inside of `layoutSubviews()`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I mean   let radius = CGFloat(layer.frame.height / 2.5)
  gradientLayer.frame = layer.frame

Comment: Ok yeah I did try `let radius = CGFloat(layer.frame.height / 2.5)` with `progressLayer.frame = layer.bounds` and `progressLayer.frame = self.bounds` . I even removed the `gradientLayer` to make things easier to just deal with the `progressLayer` by itself.

Comment: This part? let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: layer.center..  ?

Comment: Just tried it, the error was `Value of type CALayer has no member center`. Thanks for all the help so far! Still haven't got it so if you think of anything, please let me know. : )