# CAGradientLayer isn't spanning the whole width of my button - xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cagradientlayer

I'm new to xcode and I am placing a gradient layer over a button and it is not filling the whole width. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My code is here and screenshot of how it is rendering.

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = self.btnSavePhoto.bounds
let color1 = UIColor(red:0.05, green:0.29, blue:0.49, alpha:1.0).CGColor as CGColorRef
let color2 = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.23, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0).CGColor as CGColorRef
gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
self.btnSavePhoto.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your button changes it's size later on (due to autoresizing masks or constraints), but the `gradientLayer` stays of the original (smaller) size. It is caused by the fact that layers don't resize automatically. 
You can create a custom UIButton subclass that would update the sizing of a custom layer in `layoutSubviews` method.
Or you can create a custom layer subclass, although it would also require to create a UIButton subclass, as described in this question: [CALayers didn't get resized on its UIView's bounds change. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504151/calayers-didnt-get-resized-on-its-uiviews-bounds-change-why)

Comment: thank you for your answer. How would I go about creating a custom UIButton subclass that would update the sizing of a custom layer in layoutSubviews method?

Comment: Create a subclass of UIButton where in the initWithFrame method you would create your gradient layer and store it to a strong property (var), and also add it as a sublayer. (same as you do now)
Then override  layoutSubviews() method, where you would call super.layoutSubviews() and resize your layer: 
self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds.

Sorry I can't post actual code that you could immediately use, but I can do it later if you still need help :)

Comment: if you could and have the time that would be great, I can only really make cosmetic changes at this point and am a little lost when it comes to the programming side.